# How do you switch _layout.cshtml based on Screen vs Handheld? (.NET MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages, cross-browser

I am designing a small website that I want to be able to browse both on a computer as well as a mobile device.  I understand that I can swap out my CSS fairly easily for most mobile devices using the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="foo_mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="foo_screen.css">
```

However, what I really want to accomplish is swapping out the **_layout.cshtml** based on browser type (screen vs handheld - plus iPhone).

I've seen plenty of sites that redirect mobile devices to a sub-domain like **m.xyzCorp.com** but would like to avoid that if possible.

Is there any sample code or tutorials out there?  my Google-foo is weak today.

TIA

Comment: good question, I appreciate it, @Keith Barrows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In _ViewStart.cshtml have something like this

```
@{
    if (!Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MobileSiteLayout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am always pleasantly surprised at how easy MS had made things in MVC3!  Thanks for the answer, fits the bill exactly so far.